# Passing back multiple service uris

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created an asp.net web api 2 controller to manage a logical asset. As usual, the post creates it and returns the uri to the asset and the delete removes it, but I have 2 puts to perform seperate actions on the asset, so my code looks like:

```
public class Controller : ApiController
{        
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Stuff stuff)
    {
        var id = CreateNewStuff(stuff);

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = this.id }, id);
    }   

    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult ActionA(int id, ActionAStuff stuff)
    {    
        // Perform action A

        return Ok();
    }   

    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult ActionB(int id, ActionBStuff stuff)
    {    
        // Perform action B

        return Ok();
    }   

    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        // Delete the asset

        return Ok();
    }  
}
```

So that the routing understands this, my routing rules are (including the default rule):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ActionApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

This works, and feels like the system neatly seperates the put code by action, and ensures the system will reject requests for actions we do not support.

The problem is that the client that creates the asset via post does not know what the put (action) uris are, in the way it does for the asset uri via the location header returned from the post. If we change the uri form in future, the clients would break as they would be manually creating uris.

What is the correct way to either return multiple servicepoint uris from the post, or just do the above better.

Comment: The above is the correct way to go, by using the examples from the answers below. Each route represents a `resource`. You model is a representation of your data. Thinking about it like this, it makes no sense to return two url's, seen from the client perspective. I can recommend you to watch this video: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest/rest. You can only view the first chapters, but that still gives a good idea of what HTTP/REST is.

Answer (score 1):

Use Route for differentiating the actions.
For Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Admin")]
public class Controller : ApiController
{        
    [Route("ActionA")
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult ActionA(int id, ActionAStuff stuff)
    {    
        // Perform action A

        return Ok();
    }   

    [Route("ActionB")
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult ActionB(int id, ActionBStuff stuff)
    {    
        // Perform action B

        return Ok();
    }   

}
```

Then enable Attribute Routing in your webapiconfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Other Web API configuration not shown.
        }
    }
```

finally in your client you can differentiate the put URIs like below:
http(s):///api/Admin/ActionA

http(s):///api/Admin/ActionB

Comment: Thanks, but does not answer the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

One should use Route prefix for each method for differentiating.

```
[Route("ActionA")
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult ActionA(int id, ActionAStuff stuff)
{    
    // Perform action A

    return Ok();
}
```

When we configure the route using Route config from config.Routes.MapHttpRoute it has to be proper order as it added to stack and used from stack.

Once it founds the any entry from the routing table it will try to execute it.
So its better way is to use the Route Prefix.

Comment: Thanks, but does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: I am sorry that I am unable to help you at this point. But as a developer you can choose the best out of all the se answers and make your own judgement

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [link header](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#744-options-and-link-headers) to the result of the `POST` method:

1. In order to add a custom header to the `IHttpActionResult` class you could define an extension method, for example:

   ```
   public static class HttpActionResultHeaderExtensions
   { 
       public static IHttpActionResult AddHeader(this IHttpActionResult action,
                                                 string headerName, 
                                                 params string[] headerValues)
       {
           return new HeaderActionResult(action, headerName, headerValues);
       }

       private class HeaderActionResult : IHttpActionResult
       {
           private readonly IHttpActionResult action;

           private readonly Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>> header;

           public HeaderActionResult(IHttpActionResult action, 
                                     string headerName,
                                     IEnumerable<string> headerValues)
           {
               this.action = action;

               header = Tuple.Create(headerName, headerValues);
           }

           public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
           {
               var response = await action.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

               response.Headers.Add(header.Item1, header.Item2);

               return response;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add route attributes:

   ```
   [System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute("api/stuff")]
   public class Controller : ApiController
   {           
       [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
       [System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute("ActionA", Name = "ActionA")]
       public IHttpActionResult ActionA(int id, ActionAStuff stuff)
       {
           // your code            
       }

       [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
       [System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute("ActionB", Name = "ActionB")]
       public IHttpActionResult ActionB(int id, ActionBStuff stuff)
       {
           // your code    
       }         
   }
   ```
3. Extend the `POST` method adding the header link to the result:

   ```
   public IHttpActionResult Post(Stuff stuff)
   {
       var id = CreateNewStuff(stuff);

       var actionALink = this.Url.Link("ActionA", new { id = id });

       var actionBLink = this.Url.Link("ActionB", new { id = id });

       return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = id }, id)
           .AddHeader("Link", $"<{actionALink}>; rel=\"ActionA\"",     
                              $"<{actionBLink}>; rel=\"ActionB\"");        
   }
   ```
4. Extend configuration:

   ```
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.EnsureInitialized();
   ```

Comment: Not as elegant as I had hoped, but the only usable answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Web API 2 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As the name implies, attribute routing uses attributes to define routes. Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web API
You might use Attribute Routing in Web Api to solve your problems. Your Controller Action should be like this,

```
 [Route("ActionA/{id}"]
  [HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult ActionA(int id, ActionAStuff stuff)
{    
    // Perform action A

    return Ok();
}   



    [HttpPut]
   [Route("ActionB/{id}"]
    public IHttpActionResult ActionB(int id, ActionBStuff stuff)
       {    
            // Perform action B

            return Ok();
        }
```

and your HTTP request is http://localhost:1317/ActionA/1 and http://localhost:1317/ActionB/1

Comment: Thanks, but does not answer the question I asked.